# How do I import python modules from external files?

Tags: python, scripting, error

As my Addon started growing, I decided to split the ui into different files. I have several subfolders with modules that I want to register und unregister in my main script. I tried to manage this with

```
from folder.subfolder import module1
from folder.subfolder import module2

...


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.utils.register_module(module1)
    bpy.utils.register_module(module2)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(module1)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(module2)
```

Inside module1.py, it looks something like this:

```
import bpy

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "MyPanel"
    bl_idname = "...."
    bl_space_type = "...."
    bl_region_type = "...."

    def draw(self, context):
       ....
```

However, it always prints out this error message:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\addon_u
tils.py", line 350, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:/path/to/main/script.py", line 2388, in register
    bpy.utils.register_module(module1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\uti
ls\__init__.py", line 685, in register_module
    raise Exception("register_module(%r): defines no classes" % module)
Exception: register_module(<module 'module1' from 'C:/path/to/module1.py'>): defines no classes
```

What do I need to change in order to be able to register and unregister external modules properly?

Comment: Animation nodes, has a `register()` in each submodule, the addons main `register()` calls the register for each submodule. Look [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/blob/master/animation_nodes/__init__.py#L151)

Comment: I see, but if you reload Animation Nodes by pressing F8, it prints the same error message (...defines no classes). I try to circumvent this behaviour

Comment: It is common to use `importlib.reload` see [this example](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/ant_landscape/__init__.py;4b91309b122bcdcddd1854b1137407b2c4f55c7e$35). I expect that for a complex setup as above you should be able to call `unregister()` and then `register()` for each submodule when bpy is already in locals.